# Remove the default style of selected row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I know that question was ask a lot, but i only saw it in XAML code file. 
I am working on a datagrid extension, so I am in C# code file and I would like to know how to remove the default style for selected row (In my case i want nothing change in the style, I have an image in row header that show wich row is selected).

Side question, can we have a selection like "Ctrl" is pressed and how in C# code?

Thanks

**Edit**

I try this code :

```
Style oRow = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
DataTrigger oTrigger2 = new DataTrigger();
Binding oBind = new Binding();
oBind.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridRow), 1);
oBind.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridRow.IsSelectedProperty);
oTrigger2.Binding = oBind;
oTrigger2.Value = true;
oTrigger2.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Khaki));
oRow.Triggers.Add(oTrigger2);
this.RowStyle = oRow;
```

For now, i tryed to put the selected background in Khaki for test. But i get the old blue highlight.

**Edit 2**

Base on the idea of Sinatr, I change the DatagridRow for DatagridCell and ended with :

```
Style oRow = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
DataTrigger oTrigger2 = new DataTrigger();
Binding oBind = new Binding();
oBind.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridRow), 1);
oBind.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridRow.IsSelectedProperty);
oTrigger2.Binding = oBind;
oTrigger2.Value = true;
oTrigger2.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, null));
oTrigger2.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BorderBrushProperty, null));
oRow.Triggers.Add(oTrigger2);
this.RowStyle = oRow;
```

I only need to get the foreground of the row to set the foreground of the cell. But i got a new question with that solution, is ok to set background to null or i should bind it to thr row background?

Comment: I think you have to restyle `DataGrid.RowStyle`. Simply don't add any trigger for `Selector.IsSelected`, then appearance should be the same for all rows.

Comment: I try before doing Edit and it doesn't work. That why i tryed to change the color for Khaki

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `CellStyle` control template.

To example, this *stupid* templating

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <TextBlock Text="1" Background="Khaki" Foreground="Red"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

will produce this output (for just 1 `Tuple<string, string, string>`, whatever):

[image]

It stays the same for selected or not selected item.

Obviously you have to implement it more properly, but given answer should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks, base on your soltution I edit my question. I didn't mark as solved cause i got another question about my solution. Wish someone can answer me.

Comment: *Someone* then will help.